# Calling 'mv' from Python Popen with wildcard

Tags: python, shell, unix, scripting

I can't seem to get the 'mv' command to work from Python `subprocess.Popen` with a wildcard.

The code:

```
def moveFilesByType(source, destination, extension):
    params = [] 
    params.append("mv")
    params.append(source + "/*." + extension)       
    params.append(destination + "/") 

    print params

    pipe = subprocess.Popen(params, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
    result, err = pipe.communicate()

    return result
```

The output from `print params`:

```
    ['mv', '/full_path_to_folder_source/*.nib', '/full_path_to_folder_target/']
```

The paths here are shortened just for readability, but I assure that they are valid.  Calling this exact same command from a terminal works but calling in python gives the standard message about improper use of `mv`:

```
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

I read that in order for wildcards to work, I would need the parameter `shell=True` in the `Popen` call, which is present.  Any ideas why this doesn't work?  Removing `shell=True` ends up treating the asterisks as hard literals as expected.

Comment: while certainly `shutil.copytree` is a better option, you can also use `glob` to achieve the similar functions of wildcard in shell environment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a string instead of an array:

```
params = "mv /full_path_to_folder_source/*.nib /full_path_to_folder_target/"
```

When you specify arguments via the array form, the argument `'/full_path_to_folder_source/*.nib'` is passed to `mv`.  You want to force bash to expand the argument, but `Popen` won't pass each argument through the shell.

Comment: This works, but would you know why it has to be done this way?  In my other uses of `subprocess.Popen` I am passing parameters using an array.

Comment: in the array argument form only the first argument is passed through the shell.  the other arguments are passed as-is and `mv` has no concept of globbing

Answer (score 3):

You can do it without starting a new process using modules shutil and glob:

```
import glob
import shutil

def moveFilesByType(source, destination, extension):
    for path in glob.glob(source + "/*." + extension):
        shutil.move(path, destination)
```

Comment: Well, you still have to delete the files afterwards. For that, you have to check that the copy worked. Calling mv does make this easier...

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to use subprocess for this, check out [shutil.copytree](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree)